# JavaScript: play audio on a button with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I would like to play a audio file when an a-element is pressed and the element has a href.

Example:

HTML:

```
`<a href="https://example.com" class="playaudio">press me</a><br />
        <a href="https://example.com" class="playaudio">press me</a><br />
        <a href="https://example.com" class="playaudio">press me</a>`
```

Js:

```
`$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".playaudio").click(function(){
                var sound = new Audio('audio.mp3');
                sound.play();  
            });
        });`
```

I hope anyone can help me and sorry for my bad englisch :D.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please explain what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: When we use the 'a' tag it means that we want to redirect the user to some link in general. In your case you don't want the user to be directed to the link, but just to play the audio, correct?

Comment: You need the redirect to be blocked for the song to play, so use event.preventDefault() within the event

Comment: add event argument to function